# how to add a user id to each file for downloading in laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I have two tables a ''users'' and ''announcement'', which announcement table have 3 download file so I wanna add a function when a user download a file add user id to the download file?

Annoucements Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAnnoucementsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('announcements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('project_id')->unsigned();;
            $table->integer('types_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('types_id')->references('id')->on('types')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
            $table->string('project_name');
            $table->string('extension');
            $table->date('deadline');
            $table->string('biddingdocuments');
            $table->string('amendmentdocuments');
            $table->string('noticestenders');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('announcements');
}
}


Users Table 
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('securityq');
            $table->string('securitya');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('gender');

            $table->string('cname');
            $table->integer('lnumber')->unique();
            $table->string('province');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('pnumber');

            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

> ```
> userAnnoucement controller
>
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use Illuminate\Http\Response;
>
> use App\Http\Requests;
> use App\Announcements;
>
>
>
> class UserAnnoucment extends Controller
> {
>      public function index(Request $request)
>     {
>
>          $announcements = Announcements::orderBy('project_id','DESC')->paginate(5);
>         return view('userAnnoucements.index',compact('announcements'))->with('i',
> ```
>
> ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
>           }
>
> ```
>      /**
>      * Display the specified resource.
>      *
>      * @param  int  $id
>      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
>      */
>
>      public function count(){
>         $announcements = new Announcements;
>           $announcements->extension = Auth::user()->id;
>           $announcements->save();  
>       return  $announcements;
>
>      }
>
>
>
> }
> ``
> ```

Comment: Please, format your code properly. I can’t be bothered to read that.

Answer (score 0):

No problem if the site is not overly busy. Otherwise you can have conflicts if there a simultaneous download.

If there is little to no traffic, programmatically copy the download file to a temporary folder, prepend the UserID to the filename and then download from there, ie: 1024_file.pdf. If the user breaks the download or returns then the file is already there, although you may want to clear the file after each download to conserve disk space, and use the same download code each time.

On a busier service, create a folder for each user logs on (if one is not already available) and do your business in those folders.